# Is there an alternative to TOP in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to know the alternative of the TOP keyword as in MySQL. I have read about [TOP](http://www.quackit.com/sql/tutorial/sql_top.cfm) in SQL Server.

Is there any alternative to this in MySQL, or any other method in MySQL from which we can get same functionality?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ordering and limiting the results:

```
SELECT field1, field2
FROM myTable
ORDER BY field1 ASC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This is the right answer but you should review Pascal MARTIN 's answer for a deeper understanding.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `LIMIT` keyword *(See the [documentation of the `SELECT` instruction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html))* -- it goes at the end of the query :

```
select *
from your_table
where ...
limit 10
```

to get the top 10 lines

Or even :

```
select *
from your_table
where ...
limit 5, 10
```

To get 10 lines, startig from the 6th *(i.e. getting lines 6 to 15)*.

Comment: This man is always so cool and fast with his answers, great stuff man :)

Comment: @Avinash : I'm not sure I can give a definite answer that will be true for every situation, but, in some case, it will manipulate more data that you'd like *(for instance, when there is an `order by` clause, the `limit` can only be applied after the `order by` has been calculated, obviously)* ;;; @Sarfraz : thanks ;-)

Comment: let me explain my actual problem.
My problem is that i have table with 9lac record.
i just want to measure the time query execution time on my web page.
So i have decided to display only some records on page but query should manipulate all record. so how could i do it.????

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is the [**limit**](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm) clause.

**Example:**

```
    SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 0, 10
```

This will display the first 10 results from the database.

Comment: @Pascal: praising him, i like his comprehensive answers and he is also fast, not you man, you see i put my comment in pascal's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

[mysql equivalent of top](http://www.owalog.com/blog.php?myess1=5) and you can find further more about **LIMIT** in [MySql Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)