# how can I show the specific column value of last rows oh mysql database and print as a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which keeps the track of user orders . I want to show the user a invoice , hence I need to print the specific column value of last records . How can I do that ?

Comment: any table structure , sample data and desired output?

Comment: do you actually mean the last record or all previous records? if the former, perhaps you could use [`mysqli_insert_id()`](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select last row in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073923/select-last-row-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have some sort of date or id column to sort the records by so you can identify the `last` row

```
SELECT column FROM records ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

In the deplorable event you lack some sort of id to sort the rows by, you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249905/is-there-an-alternative-to-top-in-mysql) in php or some equivalent language:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM records
//set this as variable x
SELECT column FROM records WHERE 1 LIMIT x-1,1
```