# DELETE query with adding TOP

Tags: mysql

I want to delete some records that are on the top by the date and time.

the error is near 2, (the value of no_of_recordss)

```
DELETE TOP " + no_of_recordss + " FROM [upload_news] WHERE [country]='" + countryy.Text + "' ORDER BY [upload_time] ASC"
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't use TOP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249905/is-there-an-alternative-to-top-in-mysql

Comment: You mean: DELETE LIMIT " + no_of_recordss + " FROM [upload_news] WHERE [country]='" + countryy.Text + "' ORDER BY [upload_time] ASC @ John Conde

Comment: Your syntax suggests SQL Server.  The question is tagged MySQL.  What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT TOP " + no_of_recordss + " *
FROM [upload_news] 
WHERE [country]='" + countryy.Text + "' 
ORDER BY [upload_time] ASC
)
DELETE FROM CTE
```

Comment: No error occur but data is till available. @Vignesh Kumar